# Karate DSL Filter array using include inside a function

Tags: automated-tests, karate

I am trying to build a function to filter users names which do not have an "alphanumeric" char as first letter.

I call this Java method first to get all the alphanumeric chars

public static String[] alphanumericAlphabet() {
String[] AlphabetWithDigits = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};
return AlphabetWithDigits;
}

Then this in my test:

- def alphabet = alphanumericAlphabet()
- def filterUsersCall = function(user) { return alphabet.includes(user.givenName[0]) }
- def filteredUsers = karate.filter(usersList, filterUsersCall)

The second lines returns an error saying that "includes" is not a function.

How can I fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `contains`? there is a chance it got cast as Java `List` so contains might work

Comment: With contains I get "alphabet.contains is not a function" ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `#regex` is better https://github.com/intuit/karate#fuzzy-matching

But here you go:

```
* def letters = [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]
* def isValid = function(x){ return letters.contains(x.substring(0,1)) }
* def data = [ 'XXX', 'BBB', 'AAA' ]
* def temp = karate.filter(data, isValid)
```

Comment: The problem was actually in the "alphabet" variable type.
I replaced String[] with List<String> in the Java method and my test works fine now (with "contains").

Thanks to both (Babu and Peter)